# XOR Resilient Encoding

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am looking for an efficient encoding algorithm $E:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^m$ such that given $E(x)\oplus E(y)$ for $x\neq y$, we can reconstruct $x$ and $y$.
One example of such an algorithm would be mapping from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^{2^n}$ using a unit vector with $1$ only at the input coordinate. However, this is not an efficient solution in $n$.
I thought of maybe working over $GF(2^n)$ and mapping $x$ to $x^2,x$ or something of the sort, but I do not know if we can reconstruct efficiently and with certainty $x,y$ from $x^2+y^2,x+y$.

What do you think?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that $m=2n$ is possible, and this can be done explicitly in a very related fashion to your idea. It's not hard to see that this is basically optimal. In essence, what you are asking for is an injective map $E:\mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{F}_2^m$ such that the set of elements $\{E(\mathbf{x})\}_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{F}_2^n}$ forms a *Sidon set* in the group $(\mathbb{F}^m_2,+)$ (a Sidon set of an abelian group $(G,*)$ is a set of elements $A$ such that $\vert A + A\vert$ is maximal, meaning that for $i\neq j$, $a_i+a_j=a_{i'}+a_{j'}$ if and only if $\{i,j\}=\{i',j'\}$).

It turns out that the size of the largest Sidon set in $\mathbb{F}_2^{2k}$ is at least $2^k$, and can be explicitly obtained from the following construction of [Lindström](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82054677.pdf) (see also this more recent paper by [Sidorenko](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.08228.pdf) on related topics): consider all elements of the form $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^3)$ where we express $\mathbf{x}\in GF(2^k)$ as a $k$-dimensional vector over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with respect to some basis. It turns out that this forms a Sidon set, and moreover, given $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^3)+(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}^3)=(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$, one can solve for $\mathbf{x}$ (and therefore $\mathbf{y}$) by solving a quadratic equation in $GF(2^k)$. I'm *guessing* this can be done in $\text{poly}(k)$ time if you're principled about the construction/representation of $GF(2^k)$, but note that this isn't super trivial because the field has characteristic two so the quadratic formula won't help (see [this](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/MathMisc/QuGlChar2.pdf) for potentially more info).

Moving back to your case, this means that the encoding $\mathbf{x}\mapsto (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^3)$ when interpreting $\mathbf{x}\in GF(2^n)$ should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [J.G](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/53196/j-g) for your answer. For the sake of completeness and to make sure I am not missing anything, I decided to explicitly describe the decoding process. Please feel free to correct me if anything is wrong.

First of all, my suggestion earlier to map $x\to\left(x,x^2\right)$ could not possibly work since $\left(x+y\right)^2=x^2+y^2$ over $GF(2^n)$, thus $x^2+y^2$ adds no new information over $x+y$.

Now say that $(x+y,x^3+y^3)=(u,v)$, then $u^3=(x+y)^3=x^3+x^2y+y^2x+y^3=v+u\cdot xy$, namely, $xy=u^2-v/u$. It follows that $x(u-x)=u^2-v/u$, and thus $x^2+ux+(u^2+v/u)=0$, which is our quadratic equation.
To solve it, let us divide by $u^2$ and substitute $t:=x/u$ to get $t^2+t=(1+v/u^3)$. Finally, note that $t\to t^2+t$ is a linear transformation since $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$, hence we only need to solve a set of linear equations, which can be done efficiently. It should also be mentioned that all arithmetic in $GF(2^n)$ is efficiently computable.